# Обязательна ли постановка тире в конкретных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

1) Какое-то странное желание - уподобиться тем, кто тебя ненавидит.

2) Им двигало желание - уподобиться тем, кто его ненавидел.

Обязательны ли тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Обязательное тире**

При наличии слов, требующих пояснения, тире ставится обязательно (какое именно желание?):

Какое-то **странное (это) желание** — уподобиться тем, кто тебя ненавидит. Им двигало **одно желание** — уподобиться тем, кто его ненавидел. Им двигало **странное желание** — уподобиться тем, кто его ненавидел.

2) **Постановка тире определяется по тексту**

Тире обычно не ставится, если инфинитив имеет **определительное значение**:

Им двигало **желание** (какое?) уподобиться тем, кто его ненавидел. Инфинитив в значении несогласованного определения.

Тире как исключение может ставиться **в авторском тексте** для описания определенной ситуации, например:

Так не следовало поступать, но им двигало **желание** — уподобиться тем, кто его ненавидел. Обособление инфинитива делается с целью его **выделения**.

**ПАС:**  http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg82.php

Он всеми силами души всегда желал **одного** — быть вполне хорошим (Л. Т.);